# VIBRATOR_SERVICE в контексте устарело

Tags: java, android-studio

Help как по быстрому заменить чтобы работало с 6 android

предупреждение: [устаревшее] VIBRATOR_SERVICE в контексте устарело
Vibro = (Вибратор)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
.

```
 Vibrator vibro = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibro.vibrate(50);
```